# Relationship between volume viscosity and stiffness of a fluid sample

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, viscosity

I have a question regardning the relationship between volume viscosity (or bulk viscosity) and the stiffness of a fluid sample.

The volume viscosity is defined as the resistance to volume change. Is it correct to say that a high volume viscosity of a fluid sample would indicate that the fluid sample has a high stiffness, or is my understanding of this wrong?

One more thing:

Since volume viscosity is a type of viscosity, is it correct that decrease the temperature would increase the volume viscosity, or is there other thing we can do to increase the volume viscosity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about volume viscosity of fluids specifically, but in my area of continuum mechnics, viscosity and stiffness mean different things:

Stiffness parameterises the elastic behaviour, i.e. when you compress a sample with pressure $\sigma_0$, the sample will show a volume strain $\epsilon_0=\sigma_0/K$, with the bulk modulus $K$ (there might be a factor of $3$ missing here). This is an elastic effect, meaning that it happens immediately on applying the stress, and it will reverse when the stress is removed. Heuristically, the atoms get squeezed closer together by the stress, against their repulsion.

Viscosity, on the other hand, parameterises the viscous behaviour (duh), which means that the stress determines a strain rate, e.g. like $\dot\epsilon_0 = \sigma_0/\text{viscosity}$. Here, a constant stress might induce a constant rate - however that does not really make sense for a volumetric quantity, so the "viscosity" is a function of e.g. density. Purely viscous strains do not reverse themselves when the stress is removed.

Together, you could have some kind of viscoelastic substance, modelled e.g. by a Kelvin model, which can be visualised as a delayed elastic (and reversible)  response.

Heuristically, viscous strain involves temperature-dependent transitions, and so very often, lower temperatures mean higher viscosity, and so an effectively stiffer sample. Of course, for any particular substance that may or may not be true.

Comment: So, in terms of an analogy can we say that stiffness analogous to the stiffness of a spring while viscosity is analogous to it' damping constant?

Comment: @alex Not quite, or rather, it depends. There is a field of continuum mechnics called rheology, where you can basically draw diagrams to model material behaviour, and stiffness would indeed correspond to a spring, while viscosities are drawn as little dashpots. If they are parallel, you can indeed think of the viscosity as the damping constant, but if they are in series, the dashpot will continuously move. For a volumetric quantity, the first interpretation seems more likely, so your analogy is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the fluid has a high resistance to **rapid** volume changes (over and above the resistance from bulk compressibility).  The main stiffness that you typically feel is bulk compressibility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if the fluid has a higher resistance to rapid volum changes also indicate that the fluid is stiffer (since it takes more time)?

Comment: Rapid means it is force to occur in less time.

Comment: Okay, thanks again! Do you believe a decrease in the temperature would increase the volume viscosity? Or is there another thing we could do to get a higher volume viscosity of a fluid?

Comment: l don't know.  I never paid much attention to it because it is not important in the applications that I've been interested in.